Can the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm Guarantee Absolute Constant Approximation Without Back Edges?
I've been struggling with this homework question where the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm is modified to remove reverse edges from the residual graph. I tried to disprove that this approach can guarantee an absolute constant approximation factor by constructing a counterexample. However, all the counterexamples I could come up with failed, resulting in a constant $\frac{|f_{\text{max}}|}{|f'|}$, where $f_{\text{max}}$ is the maximum flow and $f'$ is the computed flow. I would appreciate if you could help me prove the statement or find a counterexample.
Thank you for helping!
Question
In a variation of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, a reduced residual graph $G'_f = (V, E'_f)$ is defined for a given flow network $G = (V, E, c, s, t)$. Here, the edge set $E'_f$ is defined as follows:
$$
E'_f := \{ (u, v) \in E \mid c(u, v) > 0 \text{ and } c_f(u, v) = c(u, v) - f(u, v) > 0 \}.
$$
Thus, $G'_f$ contains only certain edges from $E$ and excludes reverse edges $(v, u) \notin E$ for $(u, v) \in E$.
The algorithm proceeds similarly to Ford-Fulkerson by repeatedly searching for an augmenting $s$-$t$ path in $G'_f$ until no such path exists, though the order of path selection is unspecified.
The claim is that using $G'_f$ as a residual network achieves an absolute constant approximation factor $\alpha > 0$ that is independent of $|V|$, $|E|$, and $c$. Specifically, it’s claimed that the resulting flow $f'$ will satisfy:
$$
|f'| \geq \frac{|f_{\text{max}}|}{\alpha},
$$
where $f_{\text{max}}$ is the maximum flow in $G$.
Question: Can this approach actually guarantee an absolute constant approximation factor as described, or is there a counterexample showing it fails to approximate the maximum flow within a constant factor?

With all weights being 1, create a veeeery long path $s, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k, t$. Then, for each odd $i$, add the edge $s v_i$ and for each even $i$, add the edge $v_i t$.
Suppose the first DFS finds the veeeery long path.  The path found is illustrated in red and once augmented, every edge in the matching will be saturated.  The optimal flow is $\frac{n-2}{2}$, but in this scenario, 1 is returned.

In addition, by subdividing the edges that you don't use in this example, you can enforce that the solution is 1 when BFS is used.
